(Thermo-Calc) Reliability of isothermal compressibility, thermal conductivity, etc. calculations?
Recently I have been calculating various thermophysical properties in the Fe-Cr-Ni system. I am using the TCHEA5 database, which includes the Cr-Fe-Ni ternary as "critically assessed." The numbers I'm getting seem quite far off, though. As an example, a 20 at% Cr, 15 at% Ni (balance Fe) composition at 300 K is calculated to have an isothermal compressibility of 8x10^-15 1/Pa (equating to a bulk modulus of 125,000 GPa) and a thermal conductivity of 75 W/m-K.
These numbers are plainly very far off from what they should be (especially isothermal compressibility). Has anyone seen similar issues before/is there a way to get more reasonable results?
